# Suppressed figure numbers in \subcaptionbox still increase figure counter

Tags: numbering, subcaption

I want to suppress numbering in some figures. In single figures, the use of `\caption*` works fine - see first two pictures in MWE below. However, when I have two subfigures in a figure-environment (set with `\subcaptionbox`), the use of `\caption*` and `\subcaptionbox*` does suppress the figure numbering, yet the figure counter is updated, resulting in a 'missing' figure number. In the MWE below I would expect the last figure to be number two - as it is the second numbered figure, but it is numbered as three. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] %first figure - nonnumbered
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{chick}
\caption*{Non-numbered single chick}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h] %second figure, but first numbered figure - counter should be 1
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{chick}
\caption{Numbered single chick}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h] %third figure, nonnumbered
\centering
\subcaptionbox*{chick}[4cm]{\includegraphics{chick}}\hspace{1cm}
\subcaptionbox*{chick}[4cm]{\includegraphics{chick}}
\caption*{Two non-numbered chicks}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h] %fourth figure, numbered, counter should be 2, but is 3
\centering
\subcaptionbox{chick}[4cm]{\includegraphics{chick}}\hspace{1cm}
\subcaptionbox{chick}[4cm]{\includegraphics{chick}}
\caption{Two numbered chicks}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe \addtocounter{figure}{-1} will reset the counter back one.

Answer (score 2):

The `\subcaption*` command unconditionally increases the parent counter.  As John Kormylo suggests, a work around is to add

```
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
```

just before the `\caption*`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{chick}
\caption*{Non-numbered single chick}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{chick}
\caption{Numbered single chick}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subcaptionbox*{chick}[4cm]{\includegraphics{chick}}\hspace{1cm}
\subcaptionbox*{chick}[4cm]{\includegraphics{chick}}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\caption*{Two non-numbered chicks}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{chick}[4cm]{\includegraphics{chick}}\hspace{1cm}
\subcaptionbox{chick}[4cm]{\includegraphics{chick}}
\caption{Two numbered chicks}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Correcting this in the `subcaption` package does not seem to be easy.